# Check if a string contains number with more than 5 digits

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build a query that checks whether the string contains at least more than 5 consecutive digits or not.

Query;

```
SELECT count(id) as gV FROM  someTable WHERE ... title REGEXP '(\d{5,})' order by id limit 0,10
```

Sample data

```
Some text here 123456 (MATCH)
S0m3 t3xt h3r3
Some text 123 here 345
98765 Some text here (MATCH)
Some12345Text Around (MATCH)
```

Desired output

```
3 (Some text here 123456, 98765 Some text here, Some12345Text Around)
```

Is there any specific rules for regex in MySQL queries?

Comment: Five consecutive digits or five digits total? MySQL regular expressions are pretty basic but not unlike other regular expression implementations.

Comment: @tadman Atleast five consecutive digits, I am sorry, forgot mentioning it, editing question.

Comment: You have some good examples, but a few more plus if they should or shouldn't match would help.

Comment: @tadman Added a few more sample

Comment: What version of mySQL?

Comment: The `\d` is not supported by MySQL's regex engine as far as I recall. Use `[0-9]{5,}` instead.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Hmm interesting. Your approach is working as intended, could you please write as answer to mark it as complete. I will try to find out why it is not supported and update my post if I could find why

Comment: Consecutive as in next to each other in the string or consecutive in the natural numbers? ex. what about ABC13579DEF

Comment: @Error_2646 Nice catch, actually consecutive as in next to each other is what I want but I'd like to know the method of only getting the consecutive in the natural numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL's regular expression engine does not implement the `\d` "digit" expression, but instead you can represent it either as a character class range like `[0-9]` or as the special character class `[[:digit:]]`.  The curly brace repeat syntax `{5,}` is supported in the form you've attempted.

The available regular expression syntax [is described in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

So you can use either of the following forms:

```
 title REGEXP '[0-9]{5,}'
 title REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{5,}'
```

Examples:

#### Non matching:

```
> SELECT '123' REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{5,}';
+--------------------------------+
| '123' REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{5,}' |
+--------------------------------+
|                              0 |
+--------------------------------+

> SELECT '1X345' REGEXP '[0-9]{5,}';
+--------------------------------+
| '123' REGEXP '[0-9]{5,}'       |
+--------------------------------+
|                              0 |
+--------------------------------+
```

#### Matching examples:

```
> SELECT '98765 Some text here' REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{5,}';
+-------------------------------------------------+
| '98765 Some text here' REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{5,}' |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                                               1 |
+-------------------------------------------------+

> SELECT 'Some text here 123456' REGEXP '[0-9]{5,}';
+--------------------------------------------+
| 'Some text here 123456' REGEXP '[0-9]{5,}' |
+--------------------------------------------+
|                                          1 |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation, I reall do appreciate it! As @error_2646 stated what would be the optimal result to avoid strings like `Some12345Text Around`?

Comment: @Pelin sorry I never got a notification for this comment, and your question above said that particular string should match. You would need to use word boundaries like `[[:<:]][0-9]{5,}[[:>:]]`. They are also described in the docs link.